# How to export display.Javascript(jscript) object to an image on desktop

Tags: javascript, save, jupyter-notebook, displayobject

In iPython, I have a googleAPI heatmap that was generated from javascript that looks up geodata from a Twitter stream:

```
    html_template = '<div id="%s" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>'
    #This is to make sure the JS gets loaded before we try to load the maps

    time.sleep(1) 


    key = 'geo_english'

    jscript = gen_javascript(key, N=400)

    display.HTML(html_template % key)

    display.Javascript(jscript)
```

A nice heatmap is produced. I'm not sure how to save the display object to a file. 
How can I get this heatmap to be exported to a png file?

Comment: If the JS is creating a set of HTML or SVG objects, I don't think there's any neat programmatic way to turn that into a PNG from the browser (you can screenshot it, of course). You might want to look into whether the Google API you're using can produce an image.

Comment: looks like screenshot is the best way, because Google's Terms of Service actually doesn't allow you to export the interactive heatmap.https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/bX1MeJc48MU